# How to fetch parent entities only in CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data

How to fetch parent entities only in CoreData?

I have one-to-many relationship, Owner <=> Pencil entities.

The owner can have multiple pencils.

I have the following code to fetch all the owner entities but this grabs all the associated pencil entities as well

```
let ownerRequest:NSFetchRequest<Owner> = Owner.fetchRequest()
```

How do I filter out child entities?

```
// I tried this but it did not work.
ownerRequest.predicate =  NSPredicate(format: "Pencil.@count == 0")
```

Comment: Look into derived properties there is  a WWDC video from a couple of years ago that addresses this issue I don’t remember which it is but it shouldn’t be hard to find in the. Developer app

Comment: What makes you think the child objects are fetched?

Comment: You should read up on [faulting](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html) if you are not familiar with it.